# Why do WebKit browsers calculate different sizes at 100% zoom?

Tags: css, webkit, gecko

I was experimenting with text layout and have encountered an inconsistency I don't understand: WebKit browsers (i.e. Chrome/Edge) calculate the height of a block level `<p>` differently at 100% zoom than Gecko (Firefox). Sample pen at https://codepen.io/andrewhaw/pen/KKNaMNG

In Firefox, the calculated height of the `<p class="intro">` is 25.6px, which makes sense as `line-height: 1.6`; 16px (my base font-size) * 1.6 = 25.6px. I have a [visual sample of Firefox rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzsle.jpg) and [the computed box model in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLAhF.jpg).

In WebKit (tested both Chrome/Edge), the calculated height of the `<p class="intro">` is 44.5278px with the same base font-size set. This is where I am obviously missing something about how WebKit calculates sizes. I have a [visual sample of the Chrome rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ywpg5.jpg) and [the computed box model in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjJIL.jpg) from the [previously linked CodePen](https://codepen.io/andrewhaw/pen/KKNaMNG).

I have tried this on various Windows machines with the same result (I don't have access to any Macs). I do understand that expecting all rendering engines to output the same result is not in keeping with a flexible/responsive design approach, but I am mostly wondering if someone else has any suggestions on why this might be, as I must be missing something at this point.